# Would The Fork, The Witch and The Worm be the start of another series?

Tags: inheritance-cycle, christopher-paolini

The new book is scheduled to be released at the end of this year. Paolini himself has told that it would continue the story of Eragon and Saphira and in addition it will contain other stories in Alagaësia. Do you think this will turn in to a new series? Will it answer so many unanswered questions in Inheritance Cycle (like what Meona tree took from Eragon, etc.)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a future work.

Comment: While it concerns a future work, an alternative path to an answer would be a statement by the author or the publisher.

Comment: There are sufficient statements available from Paolini to answer this and it should be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It is the first book in a series, but it may not be the book you're looking for.

The full title of this book is

> "The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm: Tales from Alagaësia **(Volume 1: Eragon)**"

As the name implies, this will be followed by other books (presumably from other narrators).

> **Q:** **Volume 1???**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Heh. That does imply a Vol. 2, doesn't it? :D*
>
> <sub>([Twitter October 2018](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/1050035498838892544))</sub>
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Glad you liked it. :D There are more in the pipe.*
>
> <sub>([Reddit December 2018](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/a3cj5t/spoilers_kirkus_reviews_posted_their_review_of/eb6mmb6/?context=10000))</sub>

However, this is not the "Book V" that Paolini has been teasing since 2011.

> **Q: Is The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm the long-discussed Book Five that you said you will write?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *No. The Fork, the Witch, and the Worm is the first volume of a new series of short stories set in the world of Alagaësia. Book Five will be set after the events of this volume.*
>
> <sub>([Paolini.net FAQ October 2018](https://www.paolini.net/faq/))</sub>

**Tl;dr** Will this turn into a new series? **Yes** Will it answer so many unanswered questions in Inheritance Cycle (like what Menoa tree took from Eragon, etc.)? **Maybe some of them, but most, [including the Menoa Tree](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/8fpwfo/i_am_christopher_paolini_ama_starting_2pm_mt/dy7b3ww/?context=3), are for Book V**

Comment: Thanks! Can't wait till the book is released.

Comment: @RakihthaRR - I can't vouch for the authenticity, but there already seem to be people selling FWW on eBay.

Comment: But I thought it was supposed to be released on the end of December, right?

Comment: @RakihthaRR - Yeah, that's why I'm not sure if they're legit.

Comment: Better to wait and buy the authentic one. ;)

Comment: @RakihthaRR - I'll let you know this Thursday if it was the real deal.

Comment: @RakihthaRR - It wasn't

Comment: Ah its fine. Will buy it after the actual release.

Comment: @RakihthaRR - Much of the book is available online in the form of book previews.